# размер изображения после загрузки golang

Tags: golang

заливаю файл на сервер, хочется узнать размеры и после уже скопировать его. после функции image.DecodeConfig содержимое переменной file меняется и копирование io.Copy не происходит. ниже пример с детализацией :

```
func handlerRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {       
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil { error_handler() }
    defer file.Close()
    path := "images/"+handler.Filename
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil { error_handler() }
    defer f.Close()         
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", file) // {%!s(*io.SectionReader=&{0xc4200f8420 0 0 2954043})}
    im, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(file)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", file) // {%!s(*io.SectionReader=&{0xc4200f8420 0 28672 2954043})}
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", im) // {%!s(*color.modelFunc=&{0x608520}) %!s(int=3072) %!s(int=2048)}
    io.Copy(f, file)
}
```

в этом случаи копирование не происходит (заметил что вместо 0 после вызова DecodeConfig оказалось 28672). но если перенести image.DecodeConfig после io.Copy и открыть файл os.Open размеры получаю и копирование происходит
вот так :

```
// ... код который выше кроме image.DecodeConfig и fmt.Printf 
io.Copy(f, file)
f1, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil { error_handler() }
defer f1.Close()
im, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(f1)
```

можно ли узнать размеры изображения перед копированием ? что бы не приходилось дополнительно открывать файл :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буферизуйте чтения, вот так:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
tr := io.TeeReader(file, buf)
im, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(tr)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

mr := io.MultiReader(buf, file)
_, err = io.Copy(f, mr)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Ainar-G, как раз то что нужно :)